# What is the word for a 'hint' that might help give the solution at the end of movies?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, vocabulary, questions, cinema

For example, in *The DaVinci Code* (movie), there's an upside-down pyramid shown at the beginning of the movie. When the movie comes to an end, the whole story kind of "gathers" around this pyramid. I can't explain it properly, but it's to do with of the "Holy Grail" being (possibly) found under the pyramid.

So, the pyramid in *The DaVinci Code* is [INSERT THE WORD HERE].

Please help me find this word.

Comment: a **telltale sign** ?

Comment: Do you just mean foreshadowing?

Answer (score 6):

I think this is typically called a "foreshadowing" element or maybe "[planting and payoff](http://www.elementsofcinema.com/screenwriting/foreshadowing.html)."  It's a staple of James Bond movies -- and it's everywhere in the Back to the Future trilogy.

Answer (score 4):

"Chekhov's Gun" After Anton Chekhov, the playwright. The idea is usually  paraphrased as "If you show a gun in the first act, it must be fired by the last."

"Remove everything that has no relevance to the story. If you say in the first chapter that there is a rifle hanging on the wall, in the second or third chapter it absolutely must go off. If it's not going to be fired, it shouldn't be hanging there."
— Anton Chekhov -

Comment: [TvTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ChekhovsGun) has a whole set of variations on Chekhov's Gun:  Chekov's Gunman (when it's a person, not an object), Chekov's News (when it's a news report in the background), etc.  **Warning:** You may lose several hours of your life if you click that link.

Comment: @Bobson, many, many, many hours..

Comment: Yes, it's addictively fascinating.  Extensive cross-referencing makes it almost impossible to extricate yourself, or to even remember what you were originally seeking.

Comment: @Bobson, damn you, it happened again! Almost another whole hour spent traipsing through tropes! :D

Comment: ...irresistible, here I go ...

Comment: @Bobson Having spent too many hours, or possibly days (daze?), in TVTropes I probably learned the phrase "Chekhov's Gun" there. However, the trope itself, that everything in a tale should belong to the tale, is "older than dirt". (also a trope ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to convey that the early image of the pyramid could be used (by attentive audiences) to solve the mystery present in the film, you might call it an ***easter egg***, which [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=easter%20egg) defines as

> "A hidden item placed in a movie, television show, or otherwise visual
>   media for close watchers"

As an example of an easter egg, consider a scene from the movie Fight Club [**warning! spoilers**]. In the scene, the protagonist receives a call on a payphone, despite the fact that a sign on the payphone reads "No incoming calls allowed". This clues the audience in that the protagonist is hallucinating, but it is very unlikely to be noticed.

If the early image doesn't help you solve the mystery, you might just call it ***foreshadowing*** (in some weak sense). If the pyramidal imagery shows up throughout the work, you might try ***motif***.

Comment: Hmm, that isn't how I'd use the term "easter egg." For me, an easter egg is an interesting detail included for people with sharp eyes, *that is irrelevant to the plot of the movie as a whole.* For example, cameos of famous people. If it's foreshadowing important plot points, it's not an easter egg.

Comment: Sometimes it's used to mean an irrelevant but interesting detail. But it is also used to mean likely unnoticed details that will clue you into a resolution or acquire an ironic significance on re-watching. That 'easter egg' is not contradictory with 'foreshadowing' is corroborated by this quote: "Throughout Breaking Bad's run, show-creator Vince Gilligan and his team of writers slipped in an innumerable amoung of 'Easter Eggs' foreshadowing future events in the popular television series" (from http://whatculture.com/tv/breaking-bad-10-hidden-easter-eggs-references-probably-missed.php)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the pyramid turns out to be [***pivotal***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pivotal) to the story.

> Of crucial importance in relation to the development or success of something else:
>   *'Japan’s pivotal role in the world economy'*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pivotal

Answer (score -3):

Apparently, it's called a MacGuffin (thanks google).

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin)

An example would be rosebud from Citizen Kane

Comment: A MacGuffin is a narrative strand that seems to be important but turns out not be (e.g. Janet Leigh stealing money in Psycho)

Comment: @Dan You're thinking of a red herring.   Please read the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: @Dan: As I understand it, a MacGuffin is important to the plot. What's unimportant is the precise identity of the MacGuffin. For example, in the Citizen Kane example, the key word could have been "Bluebell" or whatever; the important thing is that it exists and what it represents, not what it actually is. Public wireless: I don't see a huge link between MacGuffins and 'hints': a MacGuffin can be non-mysterious.

Comment: @publicwireless  I had in mind the sense of M(a)cGuffin described by  Hitchcock (who did not invent the word but popularised it).  He once described it as: 

*The device, the gimmick, if you will, or the papers the spies are after... The only thing that really matters is that in the picture the plans, documents or secrets **must seem to be of vital importance to the characters. To me, the narrator, they're of no importance whatsoever***.  (my emboldening).  i.e. a McGuffin is a directorial device that facilitates the action but which is not the principal subject of the director.

Comment: Hear Hitchcock describe a McGuffin here https://vimeo.com/12375002  "...it's the thing the characters on the screen worry about but the audience don't care ..."  (i.e. it's not what the movie is 'about')

Comment: Occasionally a MacGuffin is also be a red herring, meaning that it's not actually as important as the characters think it is. But that's the exception to the rule. The rule is that it's legitimately important enough to the characters to drive the plot. It's only the specific form or content of the item that is not be important to the director or audience.

Comment: Also it's definitely not as subtle as what the OP is looking for. A MacGuffin is central to the plot, and is probably talked about incessantly.